# Connecting Android to Ford Sync via Bluetooth? 

Tags: cyanogenmod, bluetooth

I am trying to get Bluetooth audio to work with my Ford Touch. It's has worked but I can't figure out the conditions where it does.  It will pair just fine but when I try to play audio it will display a message saying it has disconnected.

I have tried doing some changes to the audio.conf as recommended on a couple of forums. But I don't see a change in behavior.

My phone is a Nexus One running CyanogenMod.

Comment: how is bluetooth audio performance with another device, like a headset?

Answer (score 2):

This issue is very likely due to the way the Ford Sync system does an initial media connection to the phone. When it connects to the phone, Ford Sync appears to immediately send a "play" command (similar to what a headset play button would do) to the phone. The problem arises when you have more than one app installed that is capable of listening for these bluetooth play events. The OS gets confused and disconnects from Ford Sync.

If you have multiple media players installed (including podcast aggregators), try removing them and re-installing them one by one. Try Ford Sync after you install each one.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue with **CyanogenMod**, I however broke my phone and got another, I was thinking it was thinking it was and HTC problem at first, but with the standard OS it is working perfectly. I have heard people could get it working by not syncing the address book, however that did not work for me.